# Unpack unsigned short in python

Tags: python, unpack

I recently needed to decode a binary file using Python.  The file contains unsigned short for storing 'Year' and 'Month' information that I want.  But the quirk is: the 'Year' is stored as unsigned short, and size is 2 bytes. The 'Month' is stored as unsigned short, too. But the size is 1 bytes. (See the file struct below)

[image: file struct]

Question is I could use Python's unpack method to decode the file,  but the unsigned short type only accepts 2 bytes data.  So how can I decode the 'Month' information?  Should I use other techniques?

```
import struct

with open("1.bin", "rb") as binary_file:
     a = struct.unpack('H',binary_file.read(2))
     print (type(a), a)
```

Comment: Are you looking at [this Performance Management thing](https://docplayer.net/61680690-Performance-management.html)? Those docs don't seem to make sense. There's even a millisecond field documented as type unsigned char, ranging from 0 to 999.

Comment: Holy man. You are?  May i have your lync?

Comment: I just googled "PM recording revision"; I've never actually heard of whatever this thing is before. If you were hoping I just happened to be a super-convenient expert on exactly this thing, well, sorry. I'm not.

Answer (score 0):

A one-byte unsigned int is known as an unsigned char. So you should be able to use this to decode that byte:

```
a = struct.unpack('B',binary_file.read(1))
```

Alternatively, you could unpack the whole record like this:

```
vals = struct.unpack('=HH5s13s5sHBBBB', binary_file.read(33))
```

Or unpack directly into named variables like this:

```
len, typ, fver, pver, rev, year, month, day, hour, minute = \
    struct.unpack('=HH5s13s5sHBBBB', binary_file.read(33))
```

Comment: Great thanks, man. But the year is stored as unsigned short( 2 bytes), why not you using struct.unpack('HH5s13s5sHBBBB', binary_file.read(33))?  one more question

Comment: Sorry, typo there. I've fixed it.

Comment: thanks, one more question: if i write "struct.unpack('HH5s13s5sHBBBB', binary_file.read(33))", Phython says: unpack requires a buffer of 34 bytes. But we only have 32 bytes totally.

Comment: When unpacking multiple items, you also need an equal sign at the start of the pattern, to tell it to use the actual width of each item with no padding (see the note about "standard size and alignment" at the top of https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html). I've fixed that. But if you only have 32 bytes available to read, you have another problem, since the format you showed requires 33 bytes.